# Binding between two DataTemplate works in one direction only

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, datagrid

I have a `DataGrid` where there are Date0, Date1, and Date2 columns. I can change the columns with a `ComboBox`.

I started to use `DataTemplate`. The `CellTemplate` uses `Date0InParameterEditingTemplate` where I bind Date0 which is not simple `DateTime` but a class. Then this class is bound to `DateEditingTemplate`. I would like to use `DateEditingTemplate` later with Date1 and Date2 as well.

The data goes well to one direction, so the `ComboBox` displays the proper date. When I select a new value in the `ComboBox` then the `SelectedItem` changes. But the content of `ContentControl` remains unchanged.

```
    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="{x:Static r:Resource.Date0}" 
                                    CellTemplate="{StaticResource Date0InParameterEditingTemplate}"/>



   <DataTemplate x:Key="DateEditingTemplate">
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
                            AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}, Path=DataContext.ValidDateObjects}" 
                  SelectedItem="{Binding Path=., Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                  DisplayMemberPath="Date" Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxError}" IsEditable="False"
                  ItemStringFormat="{StaticResource DateFormatHU}" />
    </DataTemplate>

    <!--<DataTemplate x:Key="DateEditingTemplate">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Date}"/>
    </DataTemplate>-->

    <DataTemplate x:Key="Date0InParameterEditingTemplate">
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding Date0, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                        ContentTemplate="{StaticResource DateEditingTemplate}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
```

Comment: The `ComboBox` cannot change it's own `DataContext` by binding it to the `SelectedItem`. If you want to changed `Date0` to the value of `ComboBox.SelectedItem`, then you don't need the circus with the `ContentControl`. Do you meant to change `Date0` or a property of `Date0` to the value of `SelectedItem`? Can you please provide more details regarding your data? What is the `DataContext` of your column? What is the value of `SelectedItem`? What is `Date0`? Do you meant to change `Date0.Date`?

Comment: @BionicCode `Date0` is a `ValidDate` class which has a `Date` property. I want to change the whole `Date0`. I tried this 2 level approach because the context of `Date0InParameterEditingTemplate` is `Parameter` the class which contains `Date0`, `Date1`, `Date2`. The context of `DateEditingTemplate` is `ValidDate` so the second template can be reused at `Date1`, `Date2`.